# MUI disable gutters as default on Container Component

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to set a default prop in my theme that disables gutters on Container so I don't have to write `disableGutters={true}` everytime. What am I doing wrong?

```
import { createTheme } from "@mui/material";

export const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: "#007aff",
      light: "#fff",
    },
    secondary: {
      main: "#fff",
    },
  },
  components: {
    MuiContainer: {
      defaultProps: {
        disableGutters: true,
      },
    },
  },
});
```

I have my `<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>` in index.tsx. Then somewhere down the line I have a `<Container>`

Comment: This should work. What version of MUI are you running?

Comment: Version: ^5.7.0

Comment: Do I still need to add something in that <Container> as prop?

Comment: Please provide a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) reproducing your problem.